# meaning of ''pass'' in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

in the following picture: ''pass'' means **admission** **or allowance?**
[image]

Comment: It means a travel document. From Cambridge Dictionary: _an official document or ticket showing that you have the right to go somewhere or use a particular form of transport_.

Comment: Thanks of the answer. but if we are to choose an appropriate synonym for that, which one could stand for , admission or allowance?

Comment: Well, a pass could also grant you admission to a place that isn't open to the general public. Why do you think it must be one of those two words?

Comment: This question is in the book '' Reading Journalistic Material'' which asks: which one is related or similar to pass, allowance or admission.

Comment: _Allowance_ certainly is not related. _Pass_ is not an exact synonym of _admission_, but there is more similarity between the two.

Comment: Thank you so much.